# Kurento returns null value in result

Tags: websocket, webrtc, kurento

I am running a hello-world client example from localhost.
Kurento media server is installed on Amazon ec2 instance. All TCP and UDP ports are opened.
For kurento google STUN server is configured and public IP from Amazon assigned to HttpEndPoint (announced IP) 
I manage to establish socket connection and exchange iceCandidates.

UPDATE
Stun server is configured in WebRtcEnpoint.conf.ini like this: stunServerAddress=stun.1.google.com
stunServerPort=19302

At the time of this post this STUN seems to work fine.

The last two frames always return like this:

```
{"id":26,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}

{"id":27,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}
```

So that the value is always null.

Here is the full list of frames exchanged:

```
{"id":15,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.185
{"id":16,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.185
{"id":17,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.185
{"id":18,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.210
{"id":19,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.210
{"id":20,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.210
{"id":21,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.210
{"id":22,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.210
{"id":23,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.210
{"id":24,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":"32d60f30-b7c6-4bba-a626-2af81356641d"}}  135 
13:20:50.211
{"id":25,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":"v=0\r\no=- 3652338053 3652338053 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=Kurento Media Server\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS GQCQVoS3xcQNmo4JJyGzwHIL1YzJ8QPZiQP3\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\nm=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:142379529 cname:user3741506464@host-cb3eed9a\r\na=ice-ufrag:Rk14\r\na=ice-pwd:N8cBI2tYxNA96MBRt33lr/\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 60:F6:3A:EB:47:7E:01:9C:B1:A8:7A:F2:4A:6A:98:A0:E9:1B:04:64:E9:76:04:AF:2F:19:96:FC:27:38:4D:B7\r\nm=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100\r\nb=AS:500\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:video\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=ssrc:3535835016 cname:user3741506464@host-cb3eed9a\r\na=ice-ufrag:Rk14\r\na=ice-pwd:N8cBI2tYxNA96MBRt33lr/\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 60:F6:3A:EB:47:7E:01:9C:B1:A8:7A:F2:4A:6A:98:A0:E9:1B:04:64:E9:76:04:AF:2F:19:96:FC:27:38:4D:B7\r\n"}}    1389    
13:20:50.211
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 10.189.139.160 44044 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.215
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 10.189.139.160 44044 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.215
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 10.189.139.160 46539 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.215
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 10.189.139.160 46539 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.535
{"id":26,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.535
{"id":27,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"4b9642c4-5d42-41e0-ba61-83698b85552f","value":null}}    101 
13:20:50.53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your KMS is not generating STUN candidates, as you can see from this frames

```
13:20:50.211
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 10.189.139.160 44044 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.215
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 10.189.139.160 44044 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.215
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 10.189.139.160 46539 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581 
13:20:50.215
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 10.189.139.160 46539 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video"},"source":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1443349253","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"a7d787c2-c252-47e5-b576-8923f69886a0_kurento.MediaPipeline/73f8d561-6349-4d1d-b2e6-9e2743e0c8d2_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}    581
```

That means that either your STUN configuration is not right, or that the STUN server configured is not working. You can have a look at this [list](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933) of public STUN servers, and remember that you can only use IPs in your KMS configuration, as libnice does not accept CNAMEs.

---

Sidenote: `HttpEndPoint` configuration does not have any influence in WebRTC functionality

---

EDIT 1

You are using CNAMEs in your STUN configuration, which is not supported. Please read [this](http://www.kurento.org/docs/current/installation_guide.html?highlight=turn#stun-and-turn-servers) part of the documentation about how to configure KMS to use STUN/TURN. It should be something like this

```
stunServerAddress=173.194.66.127
stunServerPort=19302
```

Make sure that the server you use is working. You might need to check a couple of them.

Comment: Hi @igracia and thanks for you comment. I've edited my question with STUN configuration that I've made following a Kurento tutorial.
This server is working according to the tool you referenced. Thanks.

Comment: Your STUN configuration is not correct, as only IPs can be used. Check the updated answer, and follow link to the documentation to find more info

Comment: @OlegMezhv good to know! Please don't forget to accept the answer as valid ;)